# How to set different font color for different cell in the same row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I am using the `exceljs package to manipulate an xslx file.

Here is my code.

```
async function doExport(){
    monthlyCalendar={
        "calendarDateList": [
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 1,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 2,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 3,
                "dayOfWeek": 3,
            },  
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 4,
                "dayOfWeek": 4,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 5,
                "dayOfWeek": 5,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 6,
                "dayOfWeek": 6,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 7,
                "dayOfWeek": 0,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 8,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 9,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 10,
                "dayOfWeek": 3,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 11,
                "dayOfWeek": 4,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 12,
                "dayOfWeek": 5,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 13,
                "dayOfWeek": 6,          
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 14,
                "dayOfWeek": 0,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 15,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 16,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 17,
                "dayOfWeek": 3,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 18,
                "dayOfWeek": 4,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 19,
                "dayOfWeek": 5,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 20,
                "dayOfWeek": 6,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 21,
                "dayOfWeek": 0,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 22,
                "dayOfWeek": 1,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 23,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 24,
                "dayOfWeek": 3,
        
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 25,
                "dayOfWeek": 4,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 26,
                "dayOfWeek": 5,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": false,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 27,
                "dayOfWeek": 6,
            },
            {
                "publicHoliday": true,
                "today": false,
                "dateOfMonth": 28,
                "dayOfWeek": 0,
            }
        ],
        "noOfWorkingDay": 18
        }
    const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile('./input.xlsx');
    const worksheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let weekdayNames=['Su','M','T','W','Th','F','S'];
    let weekdayRow=worksheet1.getRow(5);
    for (let i=0;i<this.monthlyCalendar.calendarDateList.length;i++){
        let calendarDate=this.monthlyCalendar.calendarDateList[i];
        weekdayRow.getCell(calendarDate.dateOfMonth+1).value=weekdayNames[calendarDate.dayOfWeek];
        if ((calendarDate.dayOfWeek==6)||(calendarDate.publicHoliday)){
            let address=weekdayRow.getCell(calendarDate.dateOfMonth+1).address;
            console.log(weekdayRow.getCell(calendarDate.dateOfMonth+1).address);
            worksheet1.getCell(address).font = {color:{argb: 'FFFF0000'}, name: "Times New Roman", size: 12};
            break;
        }
    }
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('./output.xlsx');   
}
doExport()
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Export Completed.")
})
.catch(error=>{
    console.log("Something Wrong:"+error.stack);
})
```

I have a row that represents a month. Each cell in the row represents a date. If the date is Saturday or a public holiday, then the content of that cell will be in red, otherwise, the content of that cell will be in black.
However, the result is all the cells content in that row are changed to red, would you help to solve the problem?

The input.xlsx can be downloaded from [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/8laplj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I use the [Rich Text Value](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs?source=post_page---------------------------#rich-text-value) to solve the problem.